# 13.10 Ubuntu mouse problem

Tags: 13.10, mouse

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 13.10 and I'm currently experiencing a mouse problem. The pointer blinks very fast and most of the time is not even visible.

I've tried the solution given in a different post, which was to change something on the display settings, but without any outcome.

On 12.04 there was no such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Open a terminal an run

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
  ```
- OR run `dconf-editor`

  Navigate to `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor` and set the key `active` to `false`.

Comment: It was already false but the problem keeps appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem you can push ctrl + alt + f6 goes to tty, and then type.

```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
  sudo shutdown -r now
```

Or change mouse curser theme.

It will might work, and you can also disable mouse in settings, and then enable it again it works in kubuntu.

Comment: Why would you want to shutdown after this? Seems wrong to me and possibly dangerous if there are files open that are not saved.  Besides that: it is "sudo" not "Sudo"

Comment: You could also getting org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active=true

Comment: I mentioned getting set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active=true